# background-size: contain height always 0

Tags: html, css, responsive, background-size

I'm trying to make an image responsive, using `contain` for the `background-size`, but the height is always 0. I've set the height on the parent element, what am I missing?

```
.masthead .container {
  height: 300px;
}
.masthead-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #505050;
  background-image: url('../logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
  <div class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
      <label for="sidebar-checkbox" class="sidebar-toggle"></label>

      <h3 class="masthead-title">
        <a href="/" title="Home"></a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `<h3>` tag you're using for the background-image has zero as height. So either give the .masthead-title a fixed height or do some content into the `<h3>` or the `<a>` within.

Option 1: fixed height on element which has property background-image

```
.masthead-title {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Option 2: content inside the element which has the background-image property

```
 <h3 class="masthead-title">
   <a href="/" title="Home">Test Test Test</a>
 </h3>
```

Option 3:
keep the fixed height on the container and set the child container with the background-image property to 100% height

```
.masthead .container {
  height:300px;
}
.masthead-title {
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I forgot to add content to the h3, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a height for your `.masthead-title`.

```css
.masthead .container {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;     /* for demo only */
}

.masthead-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #505050;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100%;                /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="sidebar-checkbox" class="sidebar-toggle"></label>
        <h3 class="masthead-title">
        <a href="/" title="Home"></a>
      </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eax5k7mc/)